# What is the maximal Picard number of a surface in P^3?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a nonsingular surface in $P^3$ of degree $d$. Then the Picard number does not exceed $h^{1,1}\approx 2/3 d^3$, whereas the maximal number attained that I know is that of a Fermat surface, which is $\approx 3d^2$. What is the true maximum? Is there any literature on this subject?

Comment: Probably you have already read: http://math.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/Picmax.pdf ?

Comment: I believe that already for smooth quartic surfaces, Segre found surfaces that beat the Fermat surface.

Comment: Just to clarify, are you working in characteristic $0$?  In positive characteristic, there are Shioda's unirational surfaces, which I believe are all supersingular.

Comment: For quintic surfaces, an example with maximum Picard number $\rho = 45$ can be found at http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.3519.pdf

Comment: This quintic example is very nice, but not really smooth...

Comment: Why not? It is the minimal desingularization of a singular surface (with four $A_9$ singularities). This is a usual construction in order to produce examples with large Picard number, since exceptional curves in the resolution tend to be independent in the Neron-Severi group.

Comment: Thank you for the answers and for the ref to Beauville. From the latter I conclude that the answer is not known, nor even close. Just to clarify: I'm interested in the maximal Picard number of a nonsingular surface of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{C}P^3$, or at least in its asymptotic. The question is out of pure curiosity (as most math questions are), as the upper and lower bounds that I know differ too much ($2/3d^3$ vs. $3d^2$)!

Comment: Beauville gave a talk on surfaces with maximal Picard number a few weeks ago: http://www.math.ru.nl/~bmoonen/WorkshopDec2013.html (third talk on Tuesday). I am sorry that I did not take notes.

Comment: @Jason Starr Smooth quartics are K3, and (in characteristic zero)
their Picard number attains its maximum of $h^{1,1} = 20$.
Segre's quartic has more lines than the Fermat quartic but
both have maximal Picard number.  [Segre's surface is $T(X,Y) = T(X',Y')$ where $T$ is a homogeneous quartic whose zeros in ${\bf P}^1$ have 
tetrahedral symmetry, such as $T(X,Y) = X^4 + XY^3$; 
the surface has $64$ lines, whereas Fermat's $D(X,Y) = D(X',Y')$
has only $48$, with $D$ being a quartic such as $X^4-Y^4$
whose roots have $8$-element dihedral symmetry.]