# Hypersurfaces with maximal Picard rank

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-surfaces, hodge-theory, picard-group

Is it true that for any $d \ge 4$, there exists a smooth, degree $d$ surface $X$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$ with maximal Picard rank i.e., Picard rank of $X$ equals $h^{1,1}(X)$?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153375/what-is-the-maximal-picard-number-of-a-surface-in-p3 this seems to be an open problem

Comment: The "restating" doesn't make sense, $H^2(X,\mathbb{Z})$ is a lattice and  $H^2(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ a vector space. As for the first question, it might be true, but it is known only for $d=4$ or $6$ -- in both cases the Fermat surface does the job. You might have a look at [this paper](https://math.unice.fr/~beauvill/pubs/Picmax.pdf).

Comment: @abx: Thanks. I have corrected the mistake in the question.

Comment: @abx and $d=5$ https://arxiv.org/pdf/1308.2525.pdf

Comment: @Mere Scribe: The OP is asking for *smooth* surfaces. Schütt examples have rational singularities.

Comment: @abx You are right.